# TypeScript and ExactEqual

Tags: javascript, typescript

How to check in the most simple way if two objects are equal? I noticed that there's no method `ExactEqual()`-like, so I wonder if I should do it manually or not.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no such method. Take a look at this [**jqfaq.com**](http://jqfaq.com/what-is-the-difference-between-and/) link where it was discussed and given the best way to check. This will suitable for both **typescript** and javascript. Hope, that will help you!.

To quote the most important part of that answer:

```
//“===” means that they are identical.
//“==” means that they are equal in value.
//( == )
//Each JavaScript value is of a specific “type” (Numbers, strings, Booleans, functions, and objects). So if you try to compare a string with a number, the browser will try to convert the string into a number before doing the comparison.
//So the following will return true.
55 == “55″ //true
0 == false //true
1 == true //true
//(===)
//The === operator will not do the conversion, if two values are not the same type it will return false. In other words, this returns true only if the operands are strictly equal in value or if they are identical objects.
55 === “55″ //false
0 === false //false
1 === true //false
var a = [1, 2, 3];
var b = [1, 2, 3];
var c = a;
var is_ab_eql = (a === b); // false (Here a and b are the same type,and also have the same value)
var is_ac_eql = (a === c); // true.
//Value types (numbers):
//a === b returns true if a and b have the same value and are of the same type.
//Reference types:
//a === b returns true if a and b reference the exact same object.
//Strings:
//a === b returns true if a and b are both strings and contain the exact same characters.
var a = “ab” + “c”;
var b = “abc”;
a === b //true
a == b //true
//in thiss case the above condition will fail
var a = new String(“abc”);
var b = “abc”;
a === b //false
a == b// true
//… since a and b are not a same type.
typeof “abc”; // ‘string’
typeof new String(“abc”)); // ‘object
```

Comment: The explanation for `is_ab_eql` does not really explain anything. They are of the same type, have the same value, but `===` return `false`. Why?

Comment: "The explanation for is_ab_eql does not really explain anything."
Explanation: == means value equality, === means identity. 
As such in the above example, a and c are equal (reference the same object in memory), a and b are not strictly equal (===) as even if they happen to have the same value, they reference different memory portions.

Hope I was able to clarify above mentioned question.